# Flutter Web Unexpectedly null value after call Hot Reload

Tags: dart, flutter-web, flutter-getx

We are developing a large project with flutter web. But when we run the application in debug mode, it works fine at first, but when we make a change and hot reload/hot restart, we get an Unexpected null value error. When we build our web application again, it continues to work without any problems.

[image: Error Picture]

Error Message:

```
    The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building AnimatedBuilder(animation:
    AnimationController#6e18e(⏮ 0.000; paused), dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state:
    _AnimatedState#b099a):
    Unexpected null value.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  AnimatedBuilder
AnimatedBuilder:file:///Users/taner/Documents/GitHub/kinderbox_web/lib/view/admin/page_controller/web/page_controller_web.dart:51:15
```

page_controller_web.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:kinderbox_web/core/constant/color_constant.dart';
import 'package:kinderbox_web/core/providers/page_controller_provider.dart';
import 'package:kinderbox_web/core/providers/user_provider.dart';
import 'package:kinderbox_web/widgets/admin/drawer/web/drawer_bar.dart';
import 'package:kinderbox_web/widgets/admin/header/web/header_web.dart';

class PageControllerWeb extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Widget> pages;

  const PageControllerWeb({
    Key? key,
    required this.pages,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PageControllerWeb> createState() => _PageControllerWebState();
}

class _PageControllerWebState extends State<PageControllerWeb>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  double maxWidth = 300;
  double minWidth = 70;
  bool isCollapsed = false;
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late Animation<double> widthAnimation;

  int currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
    widthAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: maxWidth, end: minWidth)
        .animate(_animationController);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: ColorConstants.background,
        body: AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _animationController,
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? animatedWidget) {
              return SizedBox(
                height: context.height,
                width: context.width,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    DrawerBarView(
                      onTapItem: (index) {
                        setState(() {
                          currentIndex = index;
                        });
                      },
                      animationController: _animationController,
                      isColapsed: isCollapsed,
                      menuCloseTapped: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isCollapsed = !isCollapsed;
                          isCollapsed
                              ? _animationController.forward()
                              : _animationController.reverse();
                        });
                      },
                      widthAnimation: widthAnimation,
                      selectedIndex: currentIndex,
                      userModel: Get.put(UserProvider()).userData!,
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      left: widthAnimation.value,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            boxShadow: const [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.black12,
                                blurRadius: 20,
                                spreadRadius: 5,
                              )
                            ],
                            color: ColorConstants.white,
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
                            )),
                        height: context.height,
                        width: context.width,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            HeaderView(
                              userModel: Get.put(UserProvider()).userData!,
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                                child: widget.pages[currentIndex])
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }));
  }
}
```

Also i am using GetX package in my project. Could this cause such a problem?